# Postgres ts_rank_cd different result for same tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm testing out a text search query on two separate database servers, both running Postgres 9.4.4.

The row in question has the same data, and I get the same underlying `tsvector` on both servers:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g')) ||
  TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(last_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g')) ||
  TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(username, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g'))
FROM users_v1 where user_id = 123;

-- On server A:
-- user_id    | to_tsvector
-- -----------+----------------------
-- 123        | 'georg':1 'hickman':2
-- (1 row)

-- On server B:
-- user_id    | to_tsvector
-- -----------+----------------------
-- 123        | 'georg':1 'hickman':2
-- (1 row)
```

However I get a different rank when using this vector to run a query:

```
SELECT username,
 TS_RANK_CD(
   TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g')) ||
   TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(last_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g')) ||
   TO_TSVECTOR('english', REGEXP_REPLACE(username, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', 'g'))
 , PLAINTO_TSQUERY('george'))
FROM users WHERE user_id = 123;

-- On server A:
-- user_id    | ts_rank_cd
-- -----------+----------------------
-- 123        | 0.2
-- (1 row)

-- On server B:
-- user_id    | ts_rank_cd
-- -----------+----------------------
-- 123        | 0.0
-- (1 row)
```

Is the vector the only input to the rank function, or are there any server settings/anything else that affect the behaviour of `ts_rank_cd`? Is all the information stored in the vector displayed in the console output, or is there some hidden difference in it which I'm not seeing? If not what could be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: What does `PLAINTO_TSQUERY('george')` show on each system?

Comment: Aha, a difference! It returns 'georg' on the system that gives 0.2 rank, but 'george' on the other system. Thanks. So I guess this is caused by a different text search configuration, as on here? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `jjanes`'s comment, I realised that PLAINTO_TSQUERY also accepts an optional argument to specify the text search configuration. Doing

```
SELECT PLAINTO_TSQUERY('george');
```

returned `george` on one system and `georg` on the other, but doing

```
SELECT PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', 'george');
```

returned the same on both and caused the expected ranking. Doing

```
SHOW default_text_search_config;
```

Revealed `pg_catalog.english` was set as the default on one system and `pg_catalog.simple` on the other. The discrepancy can then be fixed by either explicitly passing the config in when creating the TSQUERY, or updating the default config so they are the same on both DBs.